# Writing parquet data from Azure Databricks into data lake gen2 Error

Tags: pyspark, etl, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am getting below error while writing the processed data from databricks into the container from Azure datalake:

`AnalysisException: Path dbfs:/mnt/datalakegen212/processed already exists.`

And when I visit processed container in data storage account there are no files.

I have tried everything, checking permissions but nothing helped.

Comment: Could you provide your sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue with below code:

```
df.write.parquet("/mnt/datalakegen212/")
```

The file doesn't exist in the location, but I got the same error:

[image]

I have added overwrite mode and tried with below code:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("/mnt/datalakegen212/")
```

The file wrote successfully into the location.

[image]